# R codes for Poisson Gamma mixture distribution

Tags: r, poisson, gamma-distribution, tweedie

I have already estimated my parameters namely mu, power variance, dispersion , power, shape and scale parameters of Gamma, i have claims data and i want to fit a Compound Poisson Gamma in R, how do i proceed from here? i have done a little bit of research and found the Tweedie package more precisely the commands ptweedie.inversion or ptweedie.series.Any help and/or guide will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Looks a lot like: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21807118/r-codes-for-tweedie-compound-poisson-gamma) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915116/r-codes-for-poisson-fixed-and-random-effect-for-claims-data)

Comment: Belongs on stats.stackexchange.com